# Regex for mobile phone number validation

Tags: regex

Do anyone have similar experience? I would like to write a regex to validate the key-in mobile in a form field. Mobile number either contain 11 or 8 digits, if 11 digits entry, only start with number 1 is accept, this is for China mobile no. For 8 digits only number start with number 5,6 or 9, it is Hong Kong mobile no.

Below is the regex I wrote to validate the Hong Kong mobile no.

```
/^[5,6,9]{1}[0-9]{7}$/
```

Is it possible to have one regex to validate both mobile number entry?

Best regards,

Kelvin.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it's possible with `|` (`PATTERN_A|PATTERN_B` matches `PATTERN_A` or `PATTERN_B`):

```
/^1[0-9]{10}$|^[569][0-9]{7}$/
```

BTW, remove `,` from character class. Otherwise, not only 5, 6, or 9, but also `,` is also matched.